# Why does this succulent/echeveria have brown leaves?

Tags: container-gardening, succulents

I believe this is an echeveria. I got it maybe 6 months ago and transplanted it to this pot. It has regular potting soil and one thing to note about the container is that it doesn't have a drainage hole at the bottom.

[image]

In the past month I've noticed some of the leaves in the interior are turning a brown or dark rust color.

Why is that happening? What should I do to make this plant happy? (bigger container, different soil, more water?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally normal,these are just dead leaves that weren't providing very well for the plant.  Very healthy, otherwise.  This succulent does well kept in a shallower, clay pot WITH drainage.  However you are watering seems to be working.  I'd switch from tap water (too many salts, chemicals) to distilled water.  Later, you'll be able to break this plant up into individual plants if you want to propogate or use them in your garden.  These 'baby' plants crowd the parent and other 'siblings' and cause leaves to be ineffective so the plant cuts them off, they dry up and turn brown. Use fertilizer very sparingly...otherwise your plant is just fine!